# How to change admin templates directory folder

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I set an address for the `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` setting in my project's settings.py file and also i change `APP_DIRS` to `False`.

now, all of the templates will running but when i go to `localhost:8000/admin`, it generates an error that said "Template Does Note Exists".

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/
>
> admin/index.html

i dont want to `APP_DIRS` be True.
how can i solve this problem?

this is the settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you tell the Indention to do `APP_DIRS = False` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want APPS_DIR to be TRUE, `copy templates of admin app to your template directory`. When you set APP_DIR to True django will check for a directory named templates in each apps and if found load specified templates from that directory. Else django will check for a directory with same name as of app in the global template directory if found render specified template.

In you case APP_DIR is set to False and there is no directory named as admin in global template folder. So copy template directory from django/contrib/admin/ of your virtual environment and place it in your global template directory. I suppose your global template directory is in the project directory itself.

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
```

HTH :)